# What is the best Latin word for "career"?

Tags: vocabulary, modern-life

What would be the best Latin word(s) for "career", to be used together with a specification such as "academic", "military", or "industrial"?
The Roman phrase *cursus honorum* might refer too specifically to the sequence of public offices (perhaps closer to "political career" than "career"), but that is up to debate.
Another related concept, *curriculum vitae*, refers to a specific kind of document, not the career itself.
The most suitable words I could think of are *curriculum*, *decursus*, and *cursus*, but I may be missing some good options.

I am currently inclined towards *cursus academicus/militaris/industrialis*.
(I don't know whether *industria* is a good word for "industry". If anyone is interested, please take it to a separate question. You can also ask and answer yourself!)
What do you suggest for "career" and why?

Comment: In my case *procursus* would fit. 'the milling about before a race begins.' Still, it's a bit late for that.

Comment: Research lead: [cursus vitae](https://m.interglot.com/de/en/Vitae%20cursus), is it different to curriculum vitae at all? See meaning II of [cursus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcursus)

Comment: @Rafael That sounds excellent! It is different from *curriculum vitae* in the important way that it's not a set phrase used in a number of languages. CV is too prone to misunderstanding, but *cursus vitae* doesn't suffer from that. Would you like to write that up as an answer? (I did read [your meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/79) on the matter.)